What is the meaning of "Exit, pursued by a bear"?
What is Austin Dickinson trying to say in this scene from Dickinson S01E05? (Timestamp 06:55)

Emily Dickinson: Be back in time for Shakespeare Club.
Austin Dickinson: "Exit, pursued by a bear"

Austin went to the blacksmith in middle of the town. Why did Austin use that phrase ? What is the meaning of it ?

Another famous use of the line: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CElAB4aXrTA

Austin is demonstrating his knowledge of Shakespeare with a quote.

"Exit, pursued by a bear" is a stage direction from Shakespeare’s The Winter’s Tale that is infamous for its hilarity and difficulty to stage. It's one of the best literary inside jokes.

Source

It also implies that you leave quickly -- if you're being pursued by a bear, you're running for your life.

@Barmar: I've only ever heard that quote used ironically (as someone slowly meanders their way out the door) and/or as an in-joke (in which case it might not even involve leaving, at least not for anyone present). It never accompanies actual running.

I didn't mean mean literally running, it's a metaphor. Consider the example in the question, he's just saying he'll rush so he gets back in time. @Martha

I think this is just an obviously Shakespearian quote, and little more than that. “Exit, pursued by a bear” is a well-known stage direction for an exit.
The reference to a bear probably had no specific bear-related significance, and other Shakespearean quotes relating to exits or going to drama groups would have served as well. They could have equally quoted Peter Quince's “At the Duke’s Oak we meet” from Midsummer Night’s Dream.
Better still, they could have used Bottom’s line before that… “We will meet, and there we may rehearse most obscenely and courageously.”

The information you’ve provided has already been covered in an existing answer. As per the guidelines outlined in the Help Center regarding why some answers are deleted, your answer may be subject to deletion.

@galacticninja My point was that the reference to a bear probably had no specific bear-related significance, and other Shakespearean quotes relating to exits or going to drama groups would have served as well. Delete my answer if you disagree.

I see. I've edited your answer to include that information.
